# How to access Webview in appium python for iOS hybrid apps

Tags: ios, webview, appium

Tried with

```
handle = self.driver.window_handles[0]
self.driver.switch_to_window(handle)
```

on emulator, but no luck. I am not able to access / manipulate the elements in the page. I don't even know if i got switched to web view.

Any suggestions on how to use web views on iOS with appium (python) ?

Answer (score 0):

`driver.window_handles[0]`is probably the current window - try inspecting `window_handles` to see what other windows are available. On iOS, the app that I test just has window handles like '1', '2', etc, and switching to the last element of window_handles usually does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code to switch to WebView , if you are using appium 1.0

```
 self.driver.switch_to.context('WEBVIEW');
```